# How to syntax highlight fragments of code in one language embedded in the source code in another language in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a custom XML file format which can contain blocks of code within certain tags.

For example:

```
<Root>
    <Sql> select * from foo </Sql>
    <MoreJunk> ... </MoreJunk>
    <Python><![CDATA[
    def Bar(*args):
        return False
    ]]></Python>
</Root>
```

How can I get Vim to use SQL syntax highlighting for the text inside `<Sql>` tags and use Python higlighting for text inside `<Python>` tags?

I know Vim can already do this because it correctly highlights Javascript inside HTML files.

I tried inspecting the HTML syntax file but couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/929134/extend-vims-syntax-highlighting-for-only-some-files shows how to extend XML coloring.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For your XML with python example you would have to do something like this:

```
runtime! syntax/xml.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @Python syntax/python.vim
syntax region pythonCode  start=+<Python>+ keepend end=+/</Python>+  contains=@Python
```

These lines will include the XML syntax and the python syntax, and the specify a python region where VIM will use the python syntax instead of the XML syntax...

Of course, all this is well documented in VIM. See *:he :syn-include* on how to include syntax files.

Comment: you might want to add ```containedin=xmlCdata``` before ```contains=@Python```

Answer (score 2):

This [document](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html) describes how to write your own syntax highlighting. You should probably be able to figure out how the HTML-syntax highlighting works with javascript, with that as a reference.