# vim rails javascript_tag highlighting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vim

The problem:

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
  // some js
<% end %>
```

When I use this method the javascript-syntax is not triggered inside the block. When I use the <script> tag it works. Is there a way to trigger the javascript syntax for the rails block in vim?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [vimembedded-syntax-highligting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519753/vimembedded-syntax-highligting), it's about similar problem. You may also complete a feature request/ issue [Tim Pope's vim-rails](http://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues) github repo.